# Why is this second backreference not working?

Tags: javascript, regex

**I want to make use of backreferences as much as possible, avoiding the duplication of combinations of many patterns.**

**Other requirements**: Use less literals without constructing `new RegExp` while maintaining generality.

> Original title: Why is this negative lookahead with capturing group not working?

For example, a string:

```
1.'2.2'.33.'4.4'.5.(…etc)
```

— I want to match the characters separated by periods, and the quoted ones are not segmented and the quotes are truncated. That is to match:

`1`, `2.2`, `33`, `4.4`, `5`, `(…etc)`.

A working regex is:

```
(?<=(["'])(?!\.)).*?(?=\1)|((?!["']|\.).)+
```

```js
console.log(
  "1.'2.2'.33.'4.4'.5.(…etc)".match(
    /(?<=(["'])(?!\.)).*?(?=\1)|((?!["']|\.).)+/g
  )
)
```

A non-working one is:

`(?<=(["'])(?!\.)).*?(?=\1)|((?!\1|\.).)+`
                               `^^`

```js
console.log(
  "1.'2.2'.33.'4.4'.5.(…etc)".match(
    /(?<=(["'])(?!\.)).*?(?=\1)|((?!\1|\.).)+/g
  )
)
```

— it does not match `1`, `33`, `5`, `(…etc)`.

Why is it (**`\1`**←`^^`) non-working and how to correct it? Thank you!

Comment: The lookbehind part of your regex is a feature not supported in many browsers; only Chrome and Android so far.

Comment: When you say "not working" is it not matching something or throw an error or what?

Comment: @VLAZ thank you and I improved my description.

Comment: @Intervalia Thank you and I clarified my question, it is not duplicate because the focus is completely different.

Comment: How about: `/(["'])[\d.]+\1|\d+/g`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main point of confusion seems to be that backreferences are not like "regex subroutines"; they don't let you reuse parts of the pattern elsewhere. What they do is they let you match the exact string that was matched before again.

For example:

```js
console.log(/(\w)\1/.test('AB'));
console.log(/(\w)\1/.test('AA'));
console.log(/(\w)\1/.test('BB'));
```

`(\w)\1` does not match `AB`, but it does match `AA` and `BB`. The `\1` part only matches the exact string that was matched by the `(\w)` group before.

In your case,

```
(?<=(["'])(?!\.)).*?(?=\1)
|
((?!\1|\.).)+
```

there are two branches separated by `|`. The second branch contains a backreference (`\1`) to a capturing group in the first branch (`(["'])`).

This can never match because the second branch is only tried if the first branch failed to match anything, but in that case the first capturing group also failed to match anything, so what string would `\1` refer to?

If the capturing group referred to by a backreference never matched anything, browsers behave as if it were the empty string.

The empty string always matches, so `(?!\1)` always fails.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(
  "1.'2.2'.33.'4.4'.5.(…etc)".match(
    /(["'])[\d.]+\1|\d+/g
  )
)
```

Comment: This answer doesn't even match the "quotes are truncated" condition and the "`(…etc)`" part.

Comment: So, do you mind modifying or deleting this (completely) unhelpful answer? Thank you.